# getting "missing client token" while accessing get API of hashicorp vault

Tags: powershell, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to get the secrets from a location in hashicorp vault busing below powershell script

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers "X-Vault-Token: $($VaultAuthToken)" -Method Get -Uri "https://{Vault URL}/{Namespace}/v1/secret/{App Path}"
```

But I'm facing below error message

```
missing client token
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: Chage `-Headers "X-Vault-Token: $($VaultAuthToken)"` to `-Headers @{'X-Vault-Token' = $VaultAuthToken}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Headers` parameter accepts a dictionary object with key-value pairs corresponding to the headers you want to add to the request, not bare strings.

Change it to the following and it should work:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{'X-Vault-Token' = $VaultAuthToken} -Method Get -Uri "https://{Vault URL}/{Namespace}/v1/secret/{App Path}"
```